# Python-style Keyword Args in C++ - good practice or bad idea?

Tags: c++, python

While trying to figure out the optimal ordering for optional parameters to a function recently, I stumbled across [this blog post](http://www.cheshirekow.com/wordpress/?p=831) and [accompanying GitHub repo](https://github.com/cheshirekow/kwargs/blob/master/include/kwargs.h), which provides a header for a Pythonic `kwargs`-like facility in C++. Though I didn't end up using it, I find myself wondering whether this is a good or not in a strongly-typed language. Having worked in Python for a while, I find the notion of a `kwargs`-like facility in my project very appealing because many of its objects/functions have a number of optional parameters (which cannot be avoided, unfortunately), yielding long lists of constructors that differ by one or two parameters and could be made much more succinct/DRY-ish.

What, if anything, is others' experience with stuff like this? Should it be avoided? Are there guidelines for it? What are the potential problems/pitfalls?

Comment: You may find interesting [N4172](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4172.htm) (take a look at the objections) and [Bring named parameters in modern C++](https://marcoarena.wordpress.com/2014/12/16/bring-named-parameters-in-modern-cpp/).

Answer (score 17):

I'm not very much familiar with [C++ kwargs](https://github.com/cheshirekow/kwargs) but a couple of disadvantages come to mind after skimming their source:

1. **It's a third-party library**. Kind of obvious, but still you need to figure a way to integrate it into your project and update the source when the original repo is changed.
2. **They require globally pre-declaring all arguments**. The simple example on the blog post has this section which is dead weight:

   ```
   #include "kwargs.h"

   // these are tags which will uniquely identify the arguments in a parameter
   // pack
   enum Keys {
     c_tag,
     d_tag
   };

   // global symbols used as keys in list of kwargs
   kw::Key<c_tag> c_key;
   kw::Key<d_tag> d_key;

   // a function taking kwargs parameter pack
   template <typename... Args>
   void foo(int a, int b, Args... kwargs) {
     // first, we construct the parameter pack from the parameter pack
     kw::ParamPack<Args...> params(kwargs...);

     ...
   ```

   Not as concise as the pythonic original.
3. **Potential binary bloat**. Your function needs to be a variadic template, so each permutation of parameters will generate the binary code anew. The compiler is often unable to see they differ in trivialities and merge the binaries.
4. **Slower compilation times**. Again, your function needs to be a template and the library itself is template-based. There's nothing wrong with templates but compilers need time to parse and instantiate them.

C++ offers native alternatives to achieve the functionality of named parameters:

1. **Struct wrappers**. Define your optional parameters as fields of a struct.

   ```
   struct foo_args {
       const char* title = "";
       int year = 1900;
       float percent = 0.0;
   };

   void foo(int a, int b, const foo_args& args = foo_args())
   {
       printf("title: %s\nyear: %d\npercent: %.2f\n",
           args.title, args.year, args.percent);
   }

   int main()
   {
       foo_args args;
       args.title = "foo title";
       args.percent = 99.99;
       foo(1, 2, args);

       /* Note: in pure C brace initalizers could be used instead
          but then you loose custom defaults -- non-initialized
          fields are always zero.

          foo_args args = { .title = "foo title", .percent = 99.99 };
       */
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. **Proxy objects**. Arguments are stored in a temporary struct which can be modified with chained setters.

   ```
   struct foo {
       // Mandatory arguments
       foo(int a, int b) : _a(a), _b(b) {}

       // Optional arguments
       // ('this' is returned for chaining)
       foo& title(const char* title) { _title = title; return *this; }
       foo& year(int year) { _year = year; return *this; }
       foo& percent(float percent) { _percent = percent; return *this; }

       // Do the actual call in the destructor.
       // (can be replaced with an explicit call() member function
       // if you're uneasy about doing the work in a destructor) 
       ~foo()
       {
           printf("title: %s\nyear: %d\npercent: %.2f\n", _title, _year, _percent);
       }

   private:
       int _a, _b;
       const char* _title = "";
       int _year = 1900;
       float _percent = 0.0;
   };


   int main()
   {
       // Under the hood:
       //  1. creates a proxy object
       //  2. modifies it with chained setters
       //  3. calls its destructor at the end of the statement
       foo(1, 2).title("foo title").percent(99.99);

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   *Note*: the boilerplate can be abstracted out to a macro at the expense of readability:

   ```
   #define foo_optional_arg(type, name, default_value)  \
       public: foo& name(type name) { _##name = name; return *this; } \
       private: type _##name = default_value

   struct foo {
       foo_optional_arg(const char*, title, "");
       foo_optional_arg(int, year, 1900);
       foo_optional_arg(float, percent, 0.0);

       ...
   ```
3. **Variadic functions**. This obviously is type-unsafe and requires knowledge of type promotions to get right. It is, however, available in pure C if C++ is not an option.

   ```
   #include <stdarg.h>

   // Pre-defined argument tags
   enum foo_arg { foo_title, foo_year, foo_percent, foo_end };

   void foo_impl(int a, int b, ...)
   {
       const char* title = "";
       int year = 1900;
       float percent = 0.0;

       va_list args;
       va_start(args, b);
       for (foo_arg arg = (foo_arg)va_arg(args, int); arg != foo_end;
           arg = (foo_arg)va_arg(args, int))
       {
           switch(arg)
           {
           case foo_title:  title = va_arg(args, const char*); break;
           case foo_year:  year = va_arg(args, int); break;
           case foo_percent:  percent = va_arg(args, double); break;
           }
       }
       va_end(args);

       printf("title: %s\nyear: %d\npercent: %.2f\n", title, year, percent);
   }

   // A helper macro not to forget the 'end' tag.
   #define foo(a, b, ...) foo_impl((a), (b), ##__VA_ARGS__, foo_end)

   int main()
   {
       foo(1, 2, foo_title, "foo title", foo_percent, 99.99);

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   *Note*: In C++ this can be made type-safe with variadic templates. The run-time overhead will be gone at the expense of slower compilation times and binary bloat.
4. [**boost::parameter**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html). Still a third-party library, albeit more established lib than some obscure github repo. Drawbacks: template-heavy.

   ```
   #include <boost/parameter/name.hpp>
   #include <boost/parameter/preprocessor.hpp>
   #include <string>

   BOOST_PARAMETER_NAME(foo)
   BOOST_PARAMETER_NAME(bar)
   BOOST_PARAMETER_NAME(baz)
   BOOST_PARAMETER_NAME(bonk)

   BOOST_PARAMETER_FUNCTION(
       (int),  // the return type of the function, the parentheses are required.
       function_with_named_parameters, // the name of the function.
       tag,  // part of the deep magic. If you use BOOST_PARAMETER_NAME you need to put "tag" here.
       (required // names and types of all required parameters, parentheses are required.
           (foo, (int)) 
           (bar, (float))
       )
       (optional // names, types, and default values of all optional parameters.
           (baz, (bool) , false)
           (bonk, (std::string), "default value")
       ) 
   )
   {
       if (baz && (bar > 1.0)) return foo;
       return bonk.size();
   }

   int main()
   {
       function_with_named_parameters(1, 10.0);
       function_with_named_parameters(7, _bar = 3.14);
       function_with_named_parameters( _bar = 0.0, _foo = 42);
       function_with_named_parameters( _bar = 2.5, _bonk= "Hello", _foo = 9);
       function_with_named_parameters(9, 2.5, true, "Hello");
   }
   ```

On a closing note, I wouldn't use this kwargs library simply because there is a number of good enough alternatives in C++ to achieve the same. I personally would opt for 1. or 2. from the (non-exhaustive) list above.

Comment: Great answer!  Out of curiosity, for approach 2, why are the internal variables `private`?  Making them `public` means they can either call the function or set the variable directly.

Comment: @sjm324, thanks. Because `struct foo` is a throw-away object just to mimic the original Python function syntax; passing name-values in one line at the call site. They could be `public` but that just wasn't the point here.

Comment: That makes sense :)

Comment: another problem that comes to mind is that the code is a lot harder to read and comprehend for experienced C++ programmers than normal code. I've worked on a program where someone had thought it a good idea to do something like #define PROCEDURE void #define BEGIN { #define END } etc. etc. because he wanted to make C look like Pascal. Say again?

Comment: Nice answer.  But it does beg the question as to why after all these years C++ still cannot do this.  Particularly for bools.  foo(happy:=true, fast:=false) is much easier to follow than foo(true, false).  (Using Visual Basic notation here!).

Comment: @Tuntable I agree all of these c++ ways are super ugly and inconvenient.